# Token mismatch exception when deploying in any VM

Tags: csrf, vert.x, csrf-token

Here is my csrf and cors handler of my vertx application

```
@Log4j2
public class CsrfVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  private final Set<HttpMethod> httpMethodSet =
      new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD));
  private final Set<String> headerSet = new HashSet<>(
      Arrays.asList("Content-Type", "Authorization", "Origin", "Accept", "X-Requested-With",
          "Cookie", "X-XSRF-TOKEN"));
  private Connection dbConnection;
  private WebClient webClient;
  private Vertx vertx;

  public void start() throws Exception {
    super.start();
    HttpServer httpServer = TestService.vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = Router.router(TestService.vertx);
    SessionStore store = LocalSessionStore.create(vertx);

    SessionHandler sessionHandler = SessionHandler.create(store)
        .setCookieSameSite(CookieSameSite.STRICT)
        .setCookieHttpOnlyFlag(false);
    router.route().handler(LoggerHandler.create());
    if (TestService.serviceConfiguration.isEnableCSRF()) {
      router.route()
          .handler(CorsHandler.create("*").allowedMethods(httpMethodSet).allowedHeaders(headerSet)
              .allowCredentials(true).addOrigin(TestService.serviceConfiguration.getFrontendUrl()));
      router.route().handler(
              CSRFHandler.create(vertx, csrfSecret()).setCookieHttpOnly(false))
          .handler(sessionHandler);
    } else {

      router.route()
          .handler(CorsHandler.create("*").allowedMethods(httpMethodSet).allowedHeaders(headerSet)
              .allowCredentials(true)).handler(sessionHandler);
    }
    dbConnection = createConnection(TestService.serviceConfiguration.getJdbcConfig());
    TestAuth testAuth = new TestAuth(TestService.serviceConfiguration.getUsername(),
        TestService.serviceConfiguration.getPassword());
    AuthenticationHandler basicAuthHandler = BasicAuthHandler.create(testAuth);
    router.route("/student/*").handler(basicAuthHandler);

    router.route("/student/add").method(HttpMethod.POST).handler(this::handleAddUser);
    router.route("/student/get").method(HttpMethod.GET).handler(this::handleGetUser);
    router.route("/student/delete").method(HttpMethod.DELETE)
        .handler(this::handleDeleteUser);
    router.route("/student/update").method(HttpMethod.PUT).handler(this::handleUpdateUser);

    httpServer.requestHandler(router).listen(TestService.serviceConfiguration.getPort());
    log.info("Console Server Verticle Started Successfully. Listening to {} port",
        TestService.serviceConfiguration.getPort());
  }
```

I am able to receive cookies in browser and send it back along with updated X-XSRF-TOKEN attached to the header

Everything works fine in my local but when deploying in VM I get the below error for all post requests
ctx.fail(403, new IllegalArgumentException("Token signature does not match"));
from csrf handler of vertx.

Here are the frontend code to add x-xsrf-token when sending requests to backend

```
createXsrfHeader(headers: HttpHeaders) {
    let xsrfToken = Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')
    let sessionToken = Cookies.get('vertx-web.session')

    if(xsrfToken)
       headers = headers.append('X-XSRF-TOKEN', xsrfToken);

    // if(xsrfToken && sessionToken)
    //    headers = headers.append('Cookie', `XSRF-TOKEN=${xsrfToken}; vertx-web.session=${sessionToken}`);
    

    return headers;
 }
```

[Adding header to post request]

```
callPostRequest(subUrl: string,reqData: any) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    headers = this.createXsrfHeader(headers);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.basicApiUrl+subUrl, reqData, {
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials : true
    }).pipe(map(resData => {
        // console.log(resData);
        return resData;
      }));
  }
```

[Adding header to put request]

```
callPutRequest(subUrl: string,reqData: any) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    headers = this.createXsrfHeader(headers);
    return this.http.put<any>(this.basicApiUrl+subUrl, reqData,{
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials : true
    }).pipe(map(resData => {
        // console.log(resData);
        return resData;
      }));
  }
```

[Adding header to delete request]

```
callDeleteRequest(subUrl: string,reqData?: any) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    headers = this.createXsrfHeader(headers);
    return this.http.delete<any>(this.basicApiUrl+subUrl, {
      headers: headers,
      withCredentials : true
    }).pipe(map(resData => {
        // console.log(resData);
        return resData;
      }));
  }
```

Is there any ways to solve it.

Comment: Perhaps you can post a minimal executable snippet of your verticle and your html file? Otherwise, it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Hi @tsegismont thanks for responding have added the snippets that you have asked for. please check on it and provide the comments. It would be a great help if I get your assistance on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is here:

```
router.route() // <--- HERE
  .handler(
    CSRFHandler.create(vertx, csrfSecret())
      .setCookieHttpOnly(false))
      .handler(sessionHandler);
```

You are telling the application to create a new `CSRF` token for each request that is happening, instead of being specific of which end points are really form-based endpoints.

Imagine the following, your form is on `/student/form` your browser may request:

```
/student/form (new CSRF token: OK)
/images/some-image-in-the-html.png  (new CSRF token: probably Wrong)
/css/styles.css  (new CSRF token: probably Wrong)
...
```

Now the issue is that the 1st call did correctly generated a token, but the following 2+ will generate new tokens too and these won't match the 1st so your tokens are always misaligned.

You probably need to be more specific with the resources you want to protect, from your code I am assuming that you probably want something like:

```
router.route(""/student/*") // <--- Froms are always here under
  .handler(
    CSRFHandler.create(vertx, csrfSecret())
      .setCookieHttpOnly(false))
      .handler(sessionHandler);
```

Be careful if calling other endpoints would affect the forms too. Note that you can add multiple handlers per route, so you can be more explicit with:

```
router.route(""/student/add")
  // 1st always CSRF checks
  .handler(
    CSRFHandler.create(vertx, csrfSecret())
      .setCookieHttpOnly(false))
  // and now we the handler that will handle the form data
  .handler(this::handleAddUser)
```

Comment: Hi I tried this approach too but it keep saying the same error. "Token mismatch" I couldn't understand the reason behind this validation. can you explain why do we need this validation and why it is failing in my case.

Why do we need this in CSRF impl
ctx.fail(403, new IllegalArgumentException("Token signature does not match"));

Comment: You use CSRF projection against cross side scripts injections, that could attempt to post data on-behalf of your users. This means that for each generated form a new unique token must be generated to avoid replay attacks, and tokens on the cookie ensure that only scripts served from your domain can read it. Now if you still have issues, the best is to create a working reproducer of the bug that we can run locally and debug. It must be some miss configuration somewhere.